# Hosting Visio Control Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Workbook

Tags: excel, vsto, visio

I am looking to host the visio control inside an Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Workbook project but I get a runtime error in one of the lines that are automatically inserted by the designer.

I can find general information on how to create VSTO Workbook projects, but nothing specific about this issue. I also filed this question in the Visio Technet forum and it got briefly addressed by a Microsoft person but the question has gone no where.

In fact I do have my project moving foward using Telerik Diagram in my task pane, but we would prefer to have Visio diagrams instead.

This is ultimately the offending line with "Internal Error"

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axDrawingControl1)).EndInit();
```

Hosting the control works fine in a regular Control library project, forms project, etc.

Repro'ing is easy.

1. Create Excel Document VSTO
2. Add task pane + visio control
3. add code to show the task-pane and run the project.

This is the full stack trace

*

```
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at R2T.Workflow.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\ramon.aldana\Source\R2T\R2T\Workflow.Designer.cs:line 196
   at R2T.Workflow..ctor() in C:\Users\ramon.aldana\Source\R2T\R2T\Workflow.cs:line 13
   at R2T.ThisWorkbook.ThisWorkbook_Startup(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\ramon.aldana\Source\R2T\R2T\ThisWorkbook.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookImpl.WorkbookExtensionImpl.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.OnStartup()
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.OnStartup()
   at R2T.ThisWorkbook.FinishInitialization() in C:\Users\ramon.aldana\Source\R2T\R2T\ThisWorkbook.Designer.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorkbookBase.Microsoft.Office.Tools.EntryPoint.FinishInitialization()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.ExecutePhase(ExecutionPhases executionPhases)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.ExecuteEntryPoints()
```

*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me like configuration issue - it simply cannot find Visio when in Excel "context". Do you have Visio/Excel of the same version (e.g. both x86 / 2016)? Office 365 / not 365? Or maybe you have two different Visio versions installed? I would recommend to try "repair" in add/remove programs for Visio. You know you must have Visio installed for the drawing control to work, right?

Comment: Thank you for all your observations and pointers @Nikolay. I do have both Excel and Visio of the same version 32-bit / 2016. It definitely looks like an Excel/Visio conflict since the control works fine on another regular C# windows project.